# Within one standard deviation rule proof, help.

Tags: statistics

The mathematical statement of the "within one standard deviation" rule is that

$$\Pr(\mu-\sigma < X < \mu + \sigma) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} \int_{\mu - \sigma}^{\mu + \sigma} \exp \left( - \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \right) \; dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-1}^1 \exp \left( - \frac{u^2}{2} \right) \; du \approx 0.682689$$

(In the integral, just make the substitution $u = (x-\mu)/\sigma)$.)

Would anyone care to show me how to go from the u-sigma and u+sigma in the integral to the -1 and +1 respectively?

Comment: In the substitution you also need to change the limits of the integral. The new upper limit is determined by inserting the old upper limit $x=\mu+\sigma$ into $u=(x-\mu)/\sigma$ and the new lower limit is determined by inserting the old lower limit $x=\mu-\sigma$.

Comment: Wow thanks alot it cleared my problems up immediatly!

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation
$\sigma$ then $U:=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ is normally distributed
with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$.

Here:

$\mu-\sigma<X<\mu+\sigma\iff-1<U<1$

and consequently:

$P\left\{ \mu-\sigma<X<\mu+\sigma\right\} =P\left\{ -1<U<1\right\} $.